# ¿Por qué "\r\n\" en microcontroladores?

Tags: html, c++, c

Hice un curso básico HTML, haciendo pruebas con el navegador y nunca tuve que poner `\r\n\` y he visto un ejemplo con un microcontrolador y sí que se pone `\r\n\`. Sé que `\r\n\` es return and new line. Pero ¿Por qué cuando se escribe en HTML sobre un archivo *.c es necesario poner `\r\n\` al final de cada línea?

1. ¿Es para que el compilador interprete que se acaba una línea en HTML y comienza otra?
2. ¿Alguien puede ser más específico o dar más información?
3. ¿Cuando es necesario ponerlo y con qué tipo de archivos?
4. ¿Por qué al hacer una página web no se pone, o muchas veces no se pone?
5. ¿Cuando es necesario ponerlo y cuando no? ¿Y para qué aplicaciones?

Ejemplo de función escrita en C con HTML con finales de línea con `\r\n\`:

```
const char systemPage[] = {
"<html><head><title>System Setting</title>\r\n\
<head>\r\n\
<style type=\"text/css\">\r\n\
body{background-color:orange}\r\n\
</style>\r\n\
</head>\r\n\
         .
         .
         .
};
```

Gracias por atender esta "curiosidad". Un saludo.

Comment: lo interesante seria saber quien va a parsear dicho archivo.. no me parece que tenga nada que ver con el html en si.. capaz necesita eso el microcontrolador del que estas hablando...

Comment: el \r\n dentro del HTML solo es para lectura humana, el navegador no los toma en cuenta, cuando haces una pagina web si se ponen solo que no se ven.

Comment: Nada que ver con el compilador, la w3c (rfc2616) recomienda el uso de `\r\n` en los __encabezados__ HTTP como final de línea: __The line terminator for message-header fields is the sequence CRLF. However, we recommend that applications, when parsing such headers, recognize a single LF as a line terminator and ignore the leading CR.__ pero no es necesario que hagas un retorno de carro por cada línea en el documento, un salto de línea (`\n`) es suficiente.

Comment: Eso depende de que aplicación lo use, por ejemplo, para los navegadores no hace falta, pero si lo abres en un editor, si no hay saltos se verá todo en una misma línea.

Comment: @ArnauCastellví _... pero si lo abres en un editor, si no hay saltos se verá todo en una misma línea_, no hay un consenso, Unix (y derivados) y OSX usan `\n` (antiguamente OSX usaba `\n\r`) y Windows usa `\r\n`.

Comment: @keine-lust Cierto, pero he escrito "si NO hay saltos" ni \n ni \r\n .

Comment: @ArnauCastellví, si, me refiero a que incluso definiendo el salto cada uno va a su p**a bola :P

Comment: @gbianchi, no diría parsear el archivo, sería parsear código html, escrito sobre un archivo *.c. No se si es común en navegadores hacer pero en microcontroladores debe serlo, ya que para modificar parámetros de un microcontrolador en tiempo real (Cambiar configuraciones de periféricos en general)me parece importante . Y para modificarlos debe ser común (detectar un get o un post o lo que sea y en función de eso parsear el código html y obtener los valores que recojas a través del servidor). Para todo esto de IoT creo que debe ser importante.

Comment: @KeineLust la w3c es un organismo para sistemas vía internet y no se si esto funciona igual para microcontroladores, ya me pierdo ahí. Lo he comprobado y sí que me compila con \n únicamente en cada línea. ¿Por qué no es necesario, a pesar de las recomendaciones, en *.htm poner tampoco \n? ¿Es por lo que comentáis, que dependiendo de qué navegador es necesario ponerlo o no? Por que yo he creado *.htm's sin poner \n y en windows y con chrome se me abre la página y se ven las soluciones correctamente (al nivel que he tocado).

Comment: @JotaCorp: La recomendación de w3c se refiere a los [encabezados o cabeceras HTTP](http://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=926:cabeceras-http-headers-que-son-y-para-que-sirven-status-authorization-user-agent-referer-cu01208f&catid=83&Itemid=212), no al cuerpo del documento. Por otro lado, los navegadores hacen lo imposible para mostrar el documento aunque esté mal formado, si se ciñeran al standard la mitad de las páginas no se verian.

Comment: @KeineLust Toda la razón. Tienes toda la razón desde arriba hasta abajo. De hecho, me di cuenta de lo que decías ("no es necesario \n en todas las líneas...."), ya que le respondí a eferion que sí compilaba si ponía sólo con el final de cada línea \n (sin necesidad de \r) pero no sabía por qué. Efectivamente tienes razón. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

> ¿Por qué cuando se escribe en HTML sobre un archivo *.c es necesario poner \r\n\ al final de cada línea?

El estándar HTML no entiende los saltos de línea. De hecho podría estar todo el HTML escrito en la misma línea y la página se seguiría mostrando correctamente.

Si alguien utiliza ese separador posiblemente sea por desconocimiento o costumbre, por "*requisitos*" del proyecto (es decir, que alguien con más poder de decisión ha dicho que tiene que ser así), o porque los editores que utiliza para verificar el HTML resultante trabajan mejor con esos saltos de línea (para visualizar el código ojo).

Comment: @KeineLust Cierto!!! vaya despiste

Comment: yo uso keil para un proyecto que estoy haciendo con un microcontrolador. Este compilador, si escribo html, sobre un .c me da error si al final de línea pongo:
1: \r\n
2: \r
3: sin nada al final de línea.
Sólo compila si pongo \r\n\ o \n\ así que supongo que será necesario para que sea correcto, por eso decía que si tenía que ver con el compilador. Aunque por arriba otros compañeros decían que no. No se la verdad.

Comment: @JotaCorp no tengo manera de probar lo que dices así que no puedo confirmarlo. Sin embargo si te puedo decir que son cadenas de texto y que eso no debería causar problemas al compilador